# How to add JSP pages to a Java application that uses Jetty

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

We are building a Java app that creates reports from various data sources.  For end user simplicity we want to serve these reports via a browser so we're planning on incorporating Jetty into our app.  However, it seems like JSP pages would prove quite useful for what we are doing.  Since I've never worked with JSP pages and have only so far created a Hello World Jetty example (I do have lots of other Java experience though) I'm wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction on how to incorporate JSP pages into our app.

Basically I'd like to have a Java app that crunches all the numbers and then uses Jetty to display a bunch of JSP pages.  Is that how it should work or am I missing something in my understanding?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just of curiosity, why did you choose Jetty? Why not use Tomcat or GlassFish?

You can make your application work only with JSP pages, but it is bad practice and not good approach for creating web application. JSP together works with Java Servlets. Basically JSP pages is used for the view, servlets works as the controllers. In servlets you providing all your application's logic and in JSP pages you display what you need.

I suggest you to start reading about [servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html), try to make a web application, understand how it works and you'll see yourself if this solution is appropriate for what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, it is important to know what to use JSPs for and what not to do.  There is also a good review of [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) here at the StackOverflow wiki.

Comment: I'm following the example here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld .  That uses Jetty via servlets if I understand it correctly.  Please let me know if that is not the case.  Thanks.

Comment: Also to answer the question why Jetty vs the others ... I wanted this app to be easy to deploy to any server ... so I'd rather have the server part of the app instead of having to setup the server and then add the app to it.